# How can i set Listview bottom end dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop functionality like this

[image]

When any item is added then bottom `RelativeLayout` will `VISIBLE`
If none of item is selected then it `GONE`

**Problem :**
I have problem like this :
[image]

**Image 1 :**
Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"  >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sprator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When none of item is selected then bottom `RelativeLayout` will `GONE` like **Image 2**

When any item is added then bottom `RelativeLayout` will `VISIBLE` like **Image 3**

Comment: u start code then post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/sprator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icoShopping"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icoCheckout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add layout_above attribute to the list. In xml it has to be below the bottom layout, because otherwise the id you give to that layout (resultLayout in my example) isn't declared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/confirmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sprator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/confirmLayout"  >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to LinearLayout, like following pseudo XML:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ListView layout_weight="1" layout_height="0dp" />
   <RelativeLayout layout_height="wrap_content" /> // bottom layout
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `ListView` above the `RelativeLayout`

Implement `OnItemClickListener` in your activity. Then when a user select ro deselect an item change the visibility of the RelativeLayout to `View.VSIBLE` or `View.GONE`

Answer (score 0):

First, give an id to your inner relative layout.

Then, use `setOnItemClickListener` to capture the click events.

Find the layout in your activity code, using :

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

You can then change the visibility with :

```
layout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
```